# App Authenticity for windows Phone 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I asked a previous question about App authenticity as provided in the following URL:
[Worklight Authenticity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033111/worklight-authenticity)

And everything is working as Provided in the solution. However, our project is now meeting another scope which is adding WindowsPhone8, according to the following URL: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/application-authenticity-protection-hybrid/

I can Implement the App authenticity to WindowsPhone8 by adding the following code to the application-descriptor.xml:

```
<windowsPhone8 securityTest="MobileSecurityTest" version="1.0">
    <uuid>b5542877-7afe-4edc-a817-5341b5027633</uuid>
    <security>
        <productId>HelloWorld</productId>
        <applicationId>fca81480-7b4a-4ed0-b387-078e8fa0c3d5</applicationId>
    </security>
</windowsPhone8>
```

The issue is when I add the "`<Security></security>`" part, getting a red line under it and the application build fail. I also checked the Design preview for application-descriptor.xml and didn't find the ability to add the security tag.

The only three options I can add are "uuid" / "pushSender"/ "allowedDomainsForRemoteImages".

The error on building the WindowsPhone8 environment is:
Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'.

we are running WL Enterprise version 6.2.0.1 with fix pack 1.
I tried to build the project on Mac, Windows 7 and Windows 8 laptops, and wasn't able to add the security tag.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are using Worklight **6.2**, yet you are following the Getting Started documentation for MobileFirst Platform ("Worklight"...) **6.3**.

Application Authenticity Protection for Windows Phone 8 is [*not available* in Worklight 6.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. So, the solution is that we need to upgrade to 6.3 to get the ability to implement the app Authenticity for WinPhon8, right?

Comment: Thank you Idan, I will raise an upgrade request to our Dev team.